# Ubuntu 15.10 LEMP Stack PHP-7.0.1-fpm Magento-2.0 error

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, mariadb, magento2

So its been 2 weeks atleast 4 hours a day trying to configure a running server.
now before you bash me for posting this in the programming section let me explain.
Ubuntu 5.10 CLI server with latest Nginx 1.9.x installed running MariaDB for mysql and installed php7.0.1 from ppa:ondrej/php repo.
Mysql works great phpmyadmin also installed working great.

all required extentions from [Magento2 devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html) installed

Magento nginx virtual config:

```
    upstream fastcgi_backend{
       server  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 104.196.51.248/magento2;
       set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2;
       set $MAGE_MODE developer;
       include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
    }
```

And my Ngnix Default config

```
    server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
       root /var/www/html;
       #Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
       index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;
       server_name 104.196.51.248;
       location / {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     }
           
       location ~ \.php$ {
       #try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
     }
```

With this configuration I'm unable to get the basic installation to show up in http://104.196.38.57/magento2/setup/ (HUGE LIST OF ERRORS using Chromes Console when loading that page but with my little knowledge of the coding I cannot identify the cause.) also i cannot install via CLI because mysql tells me I cannot connect via user@localhost (which I think is just some random error.)

Anyways the point being made here is I think php7.0.1 isn't properly identifying .js within the code and how magento is written. After looking for days if anyone else has tried this Lemp Stack. Has anyone whom has had similar issues or has attempted this combo stack ran into problems? or am I doing something thats should't work to begin with because of compatibility within Magento2 New code and php7.
That is the real IP for the server I'm testing this out on so feel free to check it out and Open Chromes Console and try the Setup all permissions are correct on the files and dirs.

Comment: Did you really mean Ubuntu 5.10? not Ubuntu 15.10? Can you post what errors you get in the Chrome Console? Re MySQL error: it means that your mysql is not up and running, type mysql -u <username> and -p if you have set it up with password, in the command prompt and make sure it is up and running.

Comment: I have zero problems running mysql commands in CLI but when trying to run "php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento <command name>" it tells me unable to connect user@localhost, But that is a command that is used to get PHP7.0 to run a magento file for the installation. I feel like my problem is between Nginx and php7, phpmyadmin works fine, mysql works fine. info.php works fine in my directory so i know php is being executed. I have tried the Magento2 Archive from http://www.magento.com/download and i have tried Git Clone the 2.0 and simular issues.